# C++ - Basic Error with Arrays of Base Classes

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, base-class

I am a bit stuck right now. I have a base class called BaseBond. ZeroCouponBond and CouponBond inherit from that class. I am looking to create an array that contains both types of bonds. Here is my code:

```
...
BaseBond port[12];

for (int i=0; i < recordCount; i++)
{
    if (bonds[i].CouponRate == 0.0)
        port[i] = new ZeroCouponBond(bonds[i]);
    else
        port[i] = new CouponBond(bonds[i]);
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘port[i]

I know this is probably a simple fix and has to do with when I can declare objects in an array, but I'm relatively new to C++ and don't know all the rules.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this using pointers:

Change the declaration to this:

```
BaseBond *port[12];
```

In your original code, you were trying to assign a pointer to `BaseBond`. So it won't compile.

Furthermore, when you use inheritance like this, you have to do it using pointers anyway to prevent object slicing.

Comment: Thank you Mystical!

Last question. Now say want to access a method of a CouponBond class, how would I go about this? I know it the array port is now an array of BaseBonds. I have to cast it as a CouponBond first to access its methods right? What is wrong with this code:
    port[i] = new CouponBond(bonds[i]);
    printf("P: %f", ((CouponBond)port[i])->getPrice());

Comment: If that method is specific to the `CouponBond` class, then you can't really do that. So you'd have to cast it - though at this point you'd have to think more carefully about whether you've designed it properly. Ideally, that method is in the `BaseBond` class and overrided by each of the subclasses.

Comment: I just saw your comment edit. In that case, you should define the `getPrice` method in the `BaseBond` class and make it virtual. (it makes sense since `getPrice` applies to all "bonds") Then you can override it with a version that's specific to `CouponBond`.